# Error when working with anti-spam in telegram bot Python Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I tried to make a message pop up when you press the button in the telegram bot too often:

```
async def anti_flood(message: types.Message, *args, **kwargs):
    m = args[0]
    await m.answer(locales.hello_user[f'anti_flood_{BotDB.user_language(message.from_user.id)}'])
```

But I am getting an error

```
`m = args[0]
        
     ~~~~^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range`
```

I used to have a simpler code and it worked, but now I am translating the bot into three languages and I need it to display this data, and here is the code that worked:

```
async def anti_flood(*args, **kwargs):
    m = args[0]
    await m.answer("Not spam :) One message per second")
```

Comment: Sorry I can't give any help for you, but can you kindly teach me how to create an antispam function for telegram bot?

Comment: Yes of course. I made everything quite simple so as not to bother with the db.
Create a question, because it is not convenient to insert code fragments here

Comment: Can u send the code to a code bin?

Comment: I do not know how to do that

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251984/antispam-in-telegram-bot

Comment: I don't have 20 reputation

Comment: Sorry to hear that but anyway thanks for your help